# C++ Conditional compilation directives: multiple files

Tags: c++, visual-studio, compilation, preprocessor

I have 2 files,`main.cpp` and `head.h`

```
//main.cpp
#define DEBUG2019 1
#include 'head.h' 
int main{
A A1;
return 0;
}

//head.h
class A{
#ifdef DEBUG2019
int p;
#endif
int q;
};
```

Look, I have defined `DEBUG2019` in main.cpp. But in my visual studio 2019, the `int p` is still greyed out in `head.h`. Why is that? Why `head.h` does not know that `DEBUG2019` has been defined? You may suggest me to define `DEBUG2019` in the header file directly. But I have to define it in `main.cpp`.

Comment: The IDE shows each file separately, it has no idea that you defined a macro in a different file. Either ignore the grayed out thing, or define the macro *in your build settings* (the IDE knows about those).

Comment: When you change your code to use `p` you'll see that it's there. The IDE is leading you astray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm concerned, you should use #include "head.h" instead of #include 'head.h'

Here is the code of main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#define DEBUG2019 1
#include "head.h"
int main()
{
A A1;
return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: @Terry Qiao Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

To define a macro in project level, you can define it as a preprocessor directive: right click and select properties then in C/C++ ->Preprocessor-> Preprocessor Definitions define your macro.

or

Define the macro in a common header file and use it in the related other files (you already did this, so you can ignore the grey area).